# Why can't I answer any question now on physics.stackexchange?

Tags: support, answers, post-ban

Should I try to raise my reputation? How should I do this? Can I remove this ban by deleting my all posts questions, etc., or should I make a new account?

Comment: I have corrected the grammatical errors. The downvoter may reconsider his/her downvote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you get hit with the automatic answer block, you get linked to a [page that describes how your situation and how to get out of it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans)

### Read it.

Now, improve your existing answers. You have some deleted link-only answers; elaborate on them and undelete. Don't ask questions or leave comments in  the answer box, such stuff gets flagged and deleted.

Do *not* delete your posts, it will exacerbate the situation.

Do *not* create a new account, it will be deleted.

In addition, please do not ask homework-like questions on this site. See [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) for more information.

Comment: **For future readers:** when the site grows large enough the team may also enable the automated *question* ban which has similar properties but applies to (well, duh!) questions instead of answers.

Comment: @dmckee FWIW it might be a good isea to get it enabled now, given the amount of homework messages/bans we hand out lately. But the current system is more personal and helpful imo, switching to this will probably stop these guys from ever contributing constructively. Then again, I doubt they do that now either.

Comment: @dmckee Site size doesn't really matter. Programmers, which is similarly sized to Physics, has question bans enabled. If you really think your site would benefit from question bans (and have compelling evidence), you should post a feature request asking SE to enable them.

Comment: @Yannis ...we're similarly-sized as ProgSE? That's encouraging and at the same time .... terrifying :o

Comment: Some of the most glaring misplaced errors come from very enthusiastic young contributors. There should be some leniency in that, as long as they do not spam the site. In some years they might become useful contributors.

Comment: @annav Yes, but in this case realize that the user was presented with multiple warnings. When the automatic question ban kicked in, they were shown a detailed post explaining exactly the plight they were in and how to get out of it. They yet came back and asked about the plight over here, on meta. To be able to participate in this site you have to be able to accept some form of feedback and learn from it -- that's not happening in this case.

Comment: The SE answer ban is pretty lenient. It's _very_ hard to hit, and by the time one hits it they are likely to have been asked to improve multiple times. Till now I have seen an exact total of three answer bans on Physics.SE.

Comment: @annav: I agree with you in that there should be some leniency. Here on Phys.SE usually new users are silently downvoted so they should be notified that they are going to be banned(to ask questions and post answers). Although some users learn over time and remove the ban. I don't agree on your last point that in some years they might become useful contributors because when one is banned it is not really easy to remove the ban and even if he/she crosses the ban he/she might start contributing non-constructively.

Comment: well, that is why I ask for leniency for young users, so that they will not be banned precipitously

Comment: @user31782 There are comments on most of your deleted answers. I've seen that downvotes has nothing to do with being new, if your posts aren't up to the mark people will downvotes. You have a lot of deleted, downvoted answers with comments. One shouldn't need the feat of being banned to improve, the fact that your posts were received negatively is enough.

Comment: @annav looking at his profile, it seems like he has had plenty of feedback. And the answer ban, again, is _extremely_ lenient, it is very hard to hit. (The disabled question ban is easier to hit). I don't have the exact numbers, but it requires quite a lot of downvoted/deleted answers.

Comment: @Manishearth This is the point, new users are not accustomed with the rules and policies. When it occurred to me I did not know what downvote means. I don't know about others but when I was banned I was shocked because I did not know what was wrong, even I had not yet read the help page, policies etc. I remember not a single person said me that he/she is downvoting. It is a way back so I do not remember exactly the things. That said this is my personal opinion and I do not want to discuss further. Regards

Comment: And you had gotten comments, in plain English (no ambiguity of meaning here). Which you had ignored.

Comment: @Manishearth You were against me always from the beginning. I _challenge_ you quote a single comment written in plain English which would had explained the reason of downvote  that was given on any of my post before I was banned. You said "_If you wish to participate here you have to be able to communicate.._" Who you are to order me, a moderator. You are not the owner of this website. One day I _shall_ become a moderator on this site. I will learn all English and will expertise Physics. It may take years or even decades but I will not forget you. I give you my word.

Comment: @user31782 http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82828/explain-what-happens-to-object-in-lift/82831#comment211144_82831, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82950/does-the-contact-area-affect-friction-forces/82952#comment172719_82952, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87057/angular-displacement/87066#comment211134_87066 are some comments that I found immediately. And after sifting through your answers it occurred to me that this ban might be self-inflicting. Most of your deleted answers are self-deleted, and a higher number of deleted answers increases the chances of a ban

Comment: And no, I have no grudge against you, though I have noticed that you have been consistently contributing content that gets flagged as low quality. That's not me flagging you, that's the community. I'm not ordering you, just stating a fact -- if you aren't taking feedback constructively, and are not coming up to the mark with respect to post quality (fwiw your current posts are not too bad), then that's a problem.

Comment: @Manishearth Read my previous comment contemplatively:"_...that was given on any of my post before I was banned_". The comments on the the posts you are linking are given be Emilio many a months later when I had removed the ban.

Comment: @user31782 I don't know when you were banned and when you lifted it. The other comments do fall in an early period though. It's good that you removed the ban.

Comment: More comments: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87089/what-is-voltage-gain-of-a-transistor-amplifier-and-how-is-it-affected-by-frequen/87092#comment177962_87092, and a deleted thread below http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87621/problem-while-calculating-work-done-by-electric-field/87629#87629

Comment: I remember it. It was a user "boyfarrel" who edited one of my [questions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/82949/23) and then people took their downvotes back and I was automatically out of the ban. It was only one person who helped me(/notified me) others were just silently downvoted and walked away and I did not know that being downvoted is bad.

Comment: This:http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87621/problem-while-calculating-work-done-by-electric-field/87629#87629 :Page not found so I cant see anything. Here"http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91170/what-is-voltage-gain-of-a-transistor-amplifier-and-how-is-it-affected-by-frequen#comment177962_87092 again no one from Phys.SE notified me. The comments were from EE.SE users after the post was migrated. Moreover the answer was written before OP's edit so my answer was completely legitimate as par OP's original question. It was intentionally downvoted, perhaps after OP's edit.

Comment: I think I gave enough evidence of it not being silent downvotes, I linked to enough comments. That is "help". While some users will fix your posts for you, many a time if a post is unclear it's only possible for the author to fix it since only the author knows the intended meaning. I would not expect this kind of help from the users.

Comment: And, since this was partly due to you deleting your posts, if you had read the answer above you would have gotten yourself out of the ban. I mentioned that deleting your own posts makes it worse  -- so undeleting deleted posts will do the reverse.

Comment: There was no positive feedback I did not know what I was to improve. I did not want to discuss it as now a days I do contribute to other sites.

Comment: _sigh_, I did link to all those comments, which counts as feedback.

Comment: Well everything seems to be resolved now, so I think it's time for this discussion to be over.